# How to change a ConfigMap of a Deployment using a script?

Tags: json, go, kubernetes

There are Deployments that may use a configmap with the name like `cm-myapp-*`. How to write a script that looks at all Deployments and reconfigures them from using some of their `cm-myapp-*` to the new specific `cm-myapp-123`?

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myapp
        image: myapp:2
        volumeMounts:
          - name: config-volume
            mountPath: /etc/myapp/
      volumes:
        - name: config-volume
          configMap:
            name: cm-myapp-9375546193
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: cm-myapp-123
data:
  myapp.conf: |
    hi
```

There is `kubectl patch` that accepts 'JSON patches', and there is `kubectl edit` that looks like interactive-only. Some `kubectl` commands accept go-templates, but they aren't for editing. Dumping the whole config gives some superfluous fields.

Can extract some stuff:

```
kubectl get deployment -o go-template --template="{{range .items}}{{\$deploymentName := .metadata.name}}{{range .spec.template.spec.volumes}}{{if .configMap}}{{\$deploymentName}} {{.configMap}}:{{end}}{{end}}{{end}}" | tr ':' '\n'

kubectl get deployment myapp -ojsonpath="{.spec.template.spec.volumes[0].configMap.name}}"
```

Need to patch it (not working):

```
kubectl patch deployment myapp -p '{ "op": "replace", "path": ".spec.template.spec.volumes[0].name", "value": "cf" }'
```

So how can it be done? What's the syntax of `kubectl patch`?

Comment: `echo "xx: cm-my-app-*" | sed s/cm-my-app-[*]/cm-my-app-123/` ?

Comment: @mh-cbon, the config returned by the Kubernetes has other fields that I'm not comfortable to apply.

Comment: I've tried to do the exact same thing and found `patch` doesn't work with multiple resources in the same file. If you split them into separate files, you should be able to use `patch` though.

Comment: @TaylorWood, it's okay, there are no files when using `kubectl patch`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), the "awk for json" to tranform the JSON document(s). I'm not sure which fields you want to change exactly, but how to adjust it should be clear from the jq argument.

```
$ cat x.json 
{
  "apiVersion": "apps/v1beta1",
  "kind": "Deployment",
  "foo": "myapp"
  "metadata": {
    "name": "myapp"
  },
  "spec": {
    "template": {
      "metadata": {
        "labels": {
          "app": "myapp"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

$ jq '
  .metadata.name = "cm-myapp-123"
| .spec.template.metadata.labels.app = "cm-myapp-123"
| .
' < x.json 
{
  "apiVersion": "apps/v1beta1",
  "kind": "Deployment",
  "foo": "myapp"
  "metadata": {
    "name": "cm-myapp-123"
  },
  "spec": {
    "template": {
      "metadata": {
        "labels": {
          "app": "cm-myapp-123"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't extract clear definitions of the deployments. I don't need `jq`, I've got `kubectl patch` already.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it would be optimal if you knew the deployments in advance. You should generate your manifests that you apply from some templating solution (I would suggest getting familiar with `helm` which is much more then just templates) and then have the configmap managed with the templating.

Comment: I don't need a templating solution, especially `helm`.

Answer (score 0):

Outputs an old config name, its index in the 'volumes' array and the name of the deployment. Filters out configs that we aren't interested in, patches all deployments.

```
#!/bin/bash

name=cm-myapp
unique_name=cm-myapp-123

# Columns: ConfigMap name, index in volumes, Deployment name.
kubectl get deployment -o go-template --template="{{range .items}}{{\$deploymentName := .metadata.name}}{{range \$i, \$v := .spec.template.spec.volumes}}{{if .configMap}}{{.configMap.name}} {{\$i}} {{\$deploymentName}}:{{end}}{{end}}{{end}}" | tr ':' '\n' |
    egrep "^$name-[^-]+ " | while read l; do
        i=$(printf '%s\n' "$l" | awk '{print $2}')
        deployment=$(printf '%s\n' "$l" | awk '{print $3}')
        kubectl patch deployment $deployment --type=json -p "[{ \"op\": \"replace\", \"path\": \"/spec/template/spec/volumes/$i/configMap/name\", \"value\": \"$unique_name\" }]"
    done
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some `kubectl patch` syntax I've used to patch images by container name:

```
-p "{\"spec\":{\"template\":{\"spec\":{\"volumes\":[{\"name\":\"myapp\",\"image\":\"$imageUri\"}]}}}}"
```

The same thing might work for you by patching the `volumes` key instead:

```
-p "{\"spec\":{\"template\":{\"spec\":{\"volumes\":[{\"name\":\"config-volume\",\"configMap\":{\"name\":\"myapp-123\"}}]}}}}"
```

> What's the syntax of kubectl patch?

The official documentation is [here](https://kubernetes-v1-4.github.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_patch/) with examples [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/#use-a-json-merge-patch-to-update-a-deployment). According to that guide, you might try setting `--type=json` on your `patch` command.

There are two syntax: [JSON Patch](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) and [JSON Merge Patch](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7386).